# What does Bump Version stand for?

Tags: git, version, terminology

I saw this comment in git many times.
What does it mean actually?

Answer (score 438, accepted):

It means to increment the version number to a new, unique value.

Comment: Does it have any special context in which it can be used?  Does it have to be the source version, or can it be a dependency version?  Can it include actually updating some component to a newer version, or is it about only changing a version number in a config file for example?  In other words, are there any technical details about how this term can be used?

Comment: Updating components or dependencies is usually annotated as "update to latest/newer" or "build against latest/newer". Other than that it's just housekeeping.

Comment: @Alexey One technical consideration I have about version bump (only in the context of sbt and Maven projects) is that development should only happen with `-SNAPSHOT` versions. This also helps avoid two people bumping the version unaware of each other. 1. bump from `-SNAPSHOT` to a release (with same version number). 2. commit 3. bump to next version number and place `-SNAPSHOT` back. 4. commit 5. push

Comment: does `2.2.1` --> `2.2.2` count as a 'bump'?

Comment: @OlehZiniak: Assuming 2.2.2 hasn't been used as a version number in the project yet, sure.

Comment: And could we say _"bump down a version from 2.2.2 to 2.2.1"_ ?!

Comment: Just to clarify, does "bump" generally mean changing *only* the version number *without* making any changes to the rest of the code? In other words, if Foo 1.9.9 is described as being bumped to 2.0.0, can I safely assume that everything else between these two versions is identical?

Comment: yes @EJMak. after testing everything this should be the last commit made in a release. after that you can make a tag (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) and or put your changes into a release branch (https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Answer (score 88):

from: 
[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/):

> ```
> $ git checkout -b release-1.2 develop
> Switched to a new branch "release-1.2"
> $ ./bump-version.sh 1.2
> Files modified successfully, version bumped to 1.2.
> $ git commit -a -m "Bumped version number to 1.2"
> [release-1.2 74d9424] Bumped version number to 1.2
> 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
> ```
>
> After creating a new branch and switching to it, we bump the version
>   number. Here, bump-version.sh is a fictional shell script that changes
>   some files in the working copy to reflect the new version. (This can
>   of course be a manual change—the point being that some files change.)
>   Then, the bumped version number is committed.

Comment: This article describes a fantastic way to work with git, by the way. Very organized and streamlined. I recommend to everyone.

Comment: Where can I have some demo bump_version script ?

Comment: [bumpversion](https://github.com/peritus/bumpversion) or [grunt-bump](https://github.com/vojtajina/grunt-bump) or [git-version-bump](https://rubygems.org/gems/git-version-bump/) or else. Depending on your language preferences.

Comment: Here is the [release.sh shell](https://gist.github.com/szxp/2b0e5e86c1350274f049a28392fc25e0) script on how I automatically bump Git tag versions

Comment: Who came to this question because he found "Bump Version" while reading that article, than found out that the answer was down there :D

Comment: @pilau A single way to work with git cannot be recommended to everyone :) Of course that comment is written in 2013 and makes total sense, but I recommend future readers to also watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_IFGpJDbeU

Comment: Where is `./bump-version.sh` script is located?

Comment: @alper the idea is that  `bump-version.sh` is your own simple bash script that is doing whatever needs to be done in your repo to bump the version to the first argument sent. In that example  `1.2`. That in case you commit the version. I have a project that doesn't commit the version and use git tags for versions instead.

Answer (score 31):

Boost, pump up, bring up, ⸻the version.

---

The etymology for you.

> https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/bump
>
> Likely emerging in the mid to late 1990s with the rise of online message boards, *bump* is popularly said to be a backronym for the phrase “bring up my post.” The term, however, may have also simply originated as an extension of the word *bump* (i.e., give something a bump, or boost.).

Answer (score 19):

It means incrementing the current version number by 1.

Comment: But hopefully you imply doing so in a way that conforms to [semver](http://semver.org/)!

Comment: Semver is mostly for libs and APIs. It doesn't make sense *everywhere*.

Comment: Why not say "update/increment version" instead if that's what it means?
It seems like jargon designed to exclude those not in the clique

Comment: @danio Isn´t this the case for all wordings? Your string doesn´t clearly separates between updating dependencies versions and version of the app/lib/software itself